# Globally override event of jquery ui autocomoplete widget

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I would like to override default focus event of autocomplete so I don't have to override it everytime I call autocomplete. However, I can't figure out how to override events with my approach. Options work fine, events not:

```
$.widget( "custom.autocompleteExt", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  autoFocus: true,
  focus: function(event, ui){
    console.log(ui);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [widget factory page](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/):

> Each event has a corresponding callback, which is exposed as an option.

On widget instantiation, event handlers are passed as options. All you need to do to have a default event handler is pass it as a default option:

```
$.widget( "custom.autocompleteExt", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  options: {
    autoFocus: true,
    focus: function(event, ui){
      console.log(ui);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
$("#my-input").autocompleteExt();
// can still be overridden with:
$("#my-input").autocompleteExt({focus:null});
```

Note that the same is true for `autoFocus` and all other options. The snippet as you have it in the question won't actually do anything.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ccfgt6w9/